# Visualforce Error (under ) must occur between tags

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to build some help text into a page layout by using a visualforce page. It is very simple (as below). However, I am receiving the error: "(under ) must occur between tags". If I delete the pageblocksection and the inputfield tags. I no longer get the error.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `apex:inputField` needs to occur between `apex:form` tags.

The developer console is frankly, kind of terrible, and will hide the tag names when it shows you an error message. Click on the error, and it'll render the html tag names, like below:

> `<apex:input>` (under `<apex:pageBlock>`) must occur between tags `<apex:form>`

Also, next time you post code here, post it as text, so other users can copy that text.

Comment: Hi battery.cord, thank you! Here is the text form of the code for future reference:

Comment: I have added the form tags - but I am still getting an error - End tag must end with a delimiter - (which it is!):

<apex:page standardController="Goal_Plan__c" tabStyle="Goal_Plan__c">
     <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageblocksection>
         <h1>
        Smart Goals
    </h1>
<apex:form>
<apex:inputField="{!Goal_Plan__c.Main_Goal__c}"></apex:inputField>
<apex:inputField="{!Goal_Plan__c.Member_Feedback__c}">
</apex:inputField>
    </apex:form>     
         </apex:pageblocksection>
          </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>

Comment: You formatted your tags wrong, `apex:input` should look like this: `<apex:inputField value="{!Goal_Plan__c.Main_Goal__c}" />`. These all seem like pretty basic mistakes, you should try some of the [basic trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals) to get a better grasp of the language fundamentals.